# Make matplotlib export figure svg without stroke

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I am trying to generate an svg file with Python and matplotlib. A simpler version of the code that I use is the following :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure()
plt.fill([0,1,0.5],[0,0,1],color = "r")
plt.fill([1.5,1,0.5],[1,0,1],color = "b")
plt.show()
plt.savefig("soedgesvg.svg")
```

So far so good the result is as expected :
[image]

But when I open it in Inkscape I get an unexpected ghost edge with no color specified. This can be seen in the following picture :

[image]

Is there a way to remove this edge in Python before exporting the svg ?

#### Edit

This occurs only when a color is specified from my experience.

Inkscape 0.92.3 and matplotlib 3.1.1

Comment: When I run this code and open it with inkscape, it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SRi3.png). This is with matplotlib 3.1.0, inkscape 0.91. Maybe you want to share your versions?

Comment: Could you zoom on a point where the two triangles meet please ? I will update the question with the versions.

Comment: Ah, ok, use `linewidth=0`.

Comment: That worked, thanks didn't thought about that. But why are the lines not showing of in matplotlib but they do in inkscape ?
Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept this as the answer to the question ?

Comment: Because the linewidth is defined in points. When you zoom inside matplotlib, the lines always keep their physical size, e.g. 1/72. of an inch. When you zoom in in Inkscape you zoom into the actual figure, up to the point where maybe your screen only shows 1/72. of an inch and hence the line will be as large as the screen.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification !

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest would you post your comments as an answer please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way too go is to add `linewidth=0` when calling `plt.fill` like so :

```py
plt.fill([0,1,0.5],[0,0,1],color = "r", linewidth=0)
plt.fill([1.5,1,0.5],[1,0,1],color = "b", linewidth=0)
```

This answer has been provided by [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) in the comments with the following explanation :

> Because the linewidth is defined in points. When you zoom inside matplotlib, the lines always keep their physical size, e.g. 1/72. of an inch. When you zoom in in Inkscape you zoom into the actual figure, up to the point where maybe your screen only shows 1/72. of an inch and hence the line will be as large as the screen.